# Android ListView divider near group header

Tags: android, listview, header, preferenceactivity, divider

I have PreferenceActivity with several PreferenceGroup. The ListView doesn't show a divider above and under the header of PreferenceGroup. How does it know whether to show that header or not?

Let's say I have a ListView with custom adapter. How can I tell it which entries are the headers and shouldn't have dividers around it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not headers, they are separators. The adapter tells the `ListView` which item is a separator by returning `false` at `isEnabled`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

> public boolean isEnabled (int position)
>
> Returns true if the item at the specified position is not a separator. (A separator is a non-selectable, non-clickable item).

Comment: Well, I call them headers because they are in my layout. Thanks.

Comment: @Sebastian Nowak: Just pointing that out because `ListView` has both _headers_ and _separators_, and they behave different.